# Flutter and Laravel API. File upload. The GET method is not supported for this route. Supported methods: POST

Tags: laravel, api, flutter, laravel-6.2

I want to upload the image from Flutter. But I am getting this error:

> The GET method is not supported for this route. Supported methods:
>   POST.

But I set my api route as `POST` method. And I also sending `POST` method request, but still I am getting this error.

But one more thing, it works on `POSTMAN` and `INSOMNIA`. There is no problem.

[image]

I use this `header`:

```
Content-Type: multipart/form-data
Authorization: ....
```

Please help me.

My route is:

```
Route::post('/avatar/update', 'Api\ProfileController@avatar_update')->name('api.avatar.update');
```

My controller:

```
public function avatar_update(Request $request){
        $request->validate(array(
            'avatar' => 'required|image',
        ));
        try{
            $image = Image::make($request->avatar)->fit(250, 250);
            $photo_name = Auth::user()->username."-".strtotime(now()).'.'.$request->avatar->extension();
            $path='images/avatars/'.$photo_name;
            $image->save($path);

            if(File::exists(Auth::user()->avatar)) {
                File::delete(Auth::user()->avatar);
            }

            Auth::user()->update([
                'avatar' => 'http://attendance.isadma.com/'.$path,
            ]);
            return response()->json([
                'status' => 1,
                'message' => 'Picture updated.',
                'image' => Auth::user()->avatar
            ], 200);
        }
        catch (\Exception $e){
            return response()->json([
                'status' => 0,
                'message' => $e->getMessage()
            ], 500);
        }
    }
```

Flutter request code:

```
@override
  Future<String> uploadProfilePic(File profilePic, String token) async {
    var postUri = Uri.parse("$url/avatar/update");
    print(profilePic.path);
    print(postUri);
    var request = http.MultipartRequest("POST", postUri);
    request.headers['authorization'] = "Bearer $token";
    request.headers['Content-Type'] = "multipart/form-data";

    request.files.add(
      await http.MultipartFile.fromPath(
        'avatar',
        profilePic.path,
        contentType: MediaType('image', 'jpg'),
        filename: basename(profilePic.path),
      ),
    );

    print(request.headers);

    request.send().then((res) async {
      print(res.headers);
      print(res.statusCode);
      print(await res.stream.bytesToString());
    }).catchError((e) {
      print(e);
    });
  }
```

Comment: You didn't mention which route/URL you are getting that error on.  My guess - your POST works fine, hits the method you expect, but your validation is failing.  When validation fails, Laravel does a GET redirect back to the page you were on.  If you don't have a GET route for that page, you'd get this error.

Answer (score 0):

make sure you are sending the csrf data (_token) in your post request

Comment: I removed all csrf verification from api routes

Comment: `protected $except = [
        'api/*'
    ];`